# Make a widget show up has a normal App

Tags: android

How to make a widget show up has a normal App?

Comment: You may wish to elaborate a bit more on what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it was to make a really basic activity with a layout with basically just text telling them how to properly add the widget

```
 public class Jump extends Activity{
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }
```

And then put this in your manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".Jump" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
     </activity>
```